# Entity Framework creates large tmp files at Informix

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using **VS 2012** and an Informix Database, which is connected to VS via DB2 Drivers. When i try to create an **ADO Entity model** from the Database only including 2 of the ca. 500 tables VS crashes and even more important the informix creates large tmp-files (250 GB).

Does anybody know something about that?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Don't know what exactly what you mean because i couldnt find any code out here as you are mentioning the Entity frame work and general error is

"The table/view  does not have a primary key defined and no valid primary key could be inferred.  To use the entity, you will need to review your schema, add the correct keys".